# workaround the GET arguments triggering functions on refresh and on "go back"?

Tags: php, jquery

Ive been building a demo of small CMS that will be mostly used for adding and editing stuff form database, and one of the requirements was to have dialogs for confirmation and and messages that the action was successful (or unsuccessful with the error explanation).

Ive dealt with it by using jquery ui dialogs. Confirmation dialogs appear on button click just before data is sent to (separate) php script via POST method and they work just fine. The "success" and "error" massages are triggered by referring back to the main page with url arguments for GET function to process and they work too. The only problem is that if user refreshes the page he gets the same massage again (also happens when he goes to other page and then goes back of course). Is there a easy workaround to this problem or is there suitable alternative to the problem of messages as a whole?

Code example:

On Main Page:

```
$val=$_GET['check'];
if ($val){
  $msg=$_GET['msg'];
  echo '<div id="error"><h4>';
  echo $msg;
  echo '</div></h4>';
  echo '<script>';
  echo '$( "#error" ).dialog({ autoOpen: true });';
  echo '$( "#error" ).dialog({ buttons: [{ text: "Close", click: function() { $( this
   ).dialog( "close" ); } } ]});';
  echo '</script>';
}
```

On php function:

```
header("Location: ../projects.php?check="true"&msg=Project%20name%20updated!");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Search google for "php flash messages"

Comment: Ok, thanks. Hope its not to complicated to implement in my code.

Comment: Can you please Provide Code?

Comment: here is added code example. I have the header call on multiple php functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thins kind of problem could be solved using sessions, in your case when the user gets prompted the message success or error, you set a value in a session parameter that means the user already saw the alert message.

```
<?php
session_start();
$val = $_GET['check'];
if ($val && !isset($_SESSION['alert'])){
      $_SESSION['alert'] = true;
      $msg = $_GET['msg'];
      echo '<div id="error"><h4>';
      echo $msg;
      echo '</div></h4>';
      echo '<script>';
      echo '$( "#error" ).dialog({ autoOpen: true });';
      echo '$( "#error" ).dialog({ buttons: [{ text: "Close", click: function() { $( this
       ).dialog( "close" ); } } ]});';
      echo '</script>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. Since i already use sessions for admin log in checks its easy and elegant.